# IE11 CSS Animation Issue

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, animation

I am using the below CSS to do a gradient scroll animation and it is working nicely apart form in IE11. (And I am guessing all other versions of IE)

It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, not tested edge yet but I am just wondering if anyone knows if this is possible to fix for IE11 at all?

It seems to be the clipping which is not working. How do I amend the code to be compatible with IE as well as all other browsers?

website is here [Link to Site](http://www.derbyshiregas.co.uk/services/)

```
    .elementor-icon .fa:before {
          background: linear-gradient(132deg, #e31372, #12a9c1, #5086bb, #6a10b4, #d49c10);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: BackgroundGradient 10s ease infinite;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

@keyframes BackgroundGradient {
                0% {background-position: 0% 50%!important;}
                50% {background-position: 100% 50%!important;}
                100% {background-position: 0% 50%!important;}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Internet Explorer. It's not you, it's Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this little fallback "hack", add -webkit- to the linear-gradient (there is also a line for Opera, but I didn't try it) :

```
.elementor-icon .fa:before {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(132deg, #e31372, #12a9c1, #5086bb, #6a10b4, #d49c10);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    animation: BackgroundGradient 10s ease infinite;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

@keyframes BackgroundGradient {
    0% {background-position: 0% 50%!important;}
    50% {background-position: 100% 50%!important;}
    100% {background-position: 0% 50%!important;}
}
```

Since IE doesn't support the webkit prefix, but Edge does, it looks OK.

Inspired by this article : http://nimbupani.com/using-background-clip-for-text-with-css-fallback.html

Comment: thanks, looks like this will work, animation doesnt work in IE but doesn't look broken at least